# Missing refs/notes when fetching in git

Tags: git, git-notes

I have a situation where I'm attempting to fetch remote git notes using the following:

```
git fetch origin refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
```

On a brand new clone of the repository, this works correctly. It pulls down 2 note namespaces:

```
> git fetch origin refs/notes/"*":refs/notes/"*"                                                                                                                    <system> <dev>
From ssh://url/android-client
 * [new ref]         refs/notes/git-ratchet-1-3.2 -> refs/notes/git-ratchet-1-test
 * [new ref]         refs/notes/git-ratchet-1-dev -> refs/notes/git-ratchet-1-test2
```

However in my current project repository, when I do that fetch, I only get one of the refs. If I manually remove the file in `.git/refs/notes/git-ratchet-1-test` and try fetching again, I pull down that file/ref.

Why am I not pulling down the other `/refs/notes/git-ratchet-1-test2`?

Answer (score 2):

The key to this is here:

> If I manually remove the file in .git/refs/notes/git-ratchet-1-test and try fetching again ...

You're manually supplying a refspec, `refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*`.  This is a "non-force" refspec, meaning: "if I already have a ref, don't update mine, keep my existing ref".

To make this an update-forcing refspec, add a `+` in front.

If you would *always* like the notes to be fetched (forcing or not), update your `git config` for that remote to add that refspec to the `fetch` set.  For instance, instead of:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

you might make this read:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
```

(you may have as many `fetch =` lines as you like, per-remote).

Comment: The logic makes sense, though I'm still not seeing the missing notes after doing a  `git fetch origin +refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*`. Am I missing a step?

Comment: Don't think you're missing anything, as long as you make sure that your shell doesn't eat the `*`s (quote them somehow if needed).